# Animated bubble chart in Flex 3/ Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4, fusioncharts, bubble-chart

I want to draw a animated bubble chart in Flex 3 / Flex 4 like the link below http://devdata.worldbank.org/DataVisualizer/

Does anyone know if this made using a readymade component or is custom developed

Any url link or source code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are looking for a kickstart, you should probably start with google charts.

Easiest to integrate in your application(though needs an internet connection always)

http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#motion_chart
(It is proper bubble chart with animations and stuff)

All you really need to do is pass the data to it.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Axiis](http://www.axiis.org), it is an open source library based on [Degrafa](http://www.degrafa.org/) that will enable you to draw complex data visualizations.

They even have an example of a [bubble chart](http://www.axiis.org/examples/PlotChartExample.html).

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

FusionCharts for Flex supports Bubble chart that would let you plot the data corresponding to the X and Y coordinates value mentioned in the XML as per your data and requirement.
Please refer to the following link for further details on the Bubble chart of the FusionCharts for Flex pack.
http://www.fusioncharts.com/flex/docs/charts/?ChartSS/Bubble.html
However, please note that the the intersecting lines at the center of the bubble as displayed on hovering the mouse on the bubble plot is currently not possible with FusionCharts for Flex. In this case only the tooltip value would be displayed on mouse-hover.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend fusion charts.  POS library and poorly coded.